# How do I get the "Supercars Pack" on PC?

Tags: need-for-speed-the-run

As far as I have played Need for Speed until today, I can replace any vehicle with another.  But all the searches I have done online do not show me anything that shows how to replace or add cars.  For example, search, "replace mclaren mp4 into a bugatti veyron supersport".  It says something about 'supercars pack' but I didn't find it for PC to download.  Can someone give me directions on where to find this, and how to install it, please?

Answer (score 1):

The "Supercar Pack" is DLC that is only available for PS3 and XBox 360.  There is no way to access this content on a PC.